Clarification on "Katav HaMehaber" in Nimukei Yosef on Baba Batra 153b
I've come across the phrase "amar hamechaber" or "katav hamechaber" several times in the Nimukei Yosef on Baba Batra, for example it appears on today's daf, Baba Batra 153b  (72a in the dapei haRif).
Could someone clarify who exactly the "mechaber" is that the Nimukei Yosef is referring to in this context? Is it a specific author or a general term for a particular work?
If "hamechaber" refers to the Rif, how did the Nimukei Yosef derive or extract this specific remark from the Rif? Is it based on an explicit statement somwhere else in another sefer, or is it inferred from the Rif's formulation?
I would greatly appreciate any clarification or insights. Thank you!

Haven't seen it but why can't he be referring to himself?

I believe a nearly clear proof that he is referring to himself from his פירוש in בבא מציעה, on page ס עמוד א of the דפי הריף in the Vilna print, first wide line where, after bringing the opinion of the רמב"ן he writes אמר המחבר ואני תמה על מורי ז"ל

Makes sense! Thanks

According to the Wikipedia article about the Nimukei Yosef, when he writes "Amar ham'chaber" he's referencing himself (as opposed to his common practice of bringing other rishonim and discussing their opinions). Wikipedia doesn't bring a source for this claim.

his own chidush

Thank you. it makes sense.

@TouitouJohn if you like this answer (or the other one) consider accepting it
